# Custom Systemd service not finishing activation

Tags: linux, keyboard, systemd, console, tty

[This page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration#Adjusting_typematic_delay_and_rate) on the Arch Wiki describes a systemd unit that can adjust the keyboard repeat rate in the tty, which I have written in my home directory and symlinked to the following directory:

```
/etc/systemd/system/kbdrate.service
-----------------------------------
[Unit]
Description=Keyboard repeat rate in tty.

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kbdrate --silent --delay 250 --rate 30
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And run the following commands to enable it and begin running now:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl enable --now kbdrate.service
```

The command will begin running and not stop until it times out, giving a timeout error in `# journalctl` (EDIT: this happened once with some combination of changes to the script, but for the version described above it just continues "activating" indefinitely). During this time, the `systemctl status` of the service shows that the service is loaded from the correct directory, is activating, and the only output is `systemd[1]: Starting Keyboard repeat rate in tty....`.

I have tried various combinations of turning it into a user service, setting `Type=simple`, `RemainAfterExit=no`, `ExecStart=/usr/bin/kbdrate` (removing the arguments), and `WantedBy=default.target` to get it to run but to no avail.

The `# kbdrate` command works fine on it's own, and setting it up as a user service fails because `Permission denied` on setting up standard input and spawning `/usr/bin/kbdrate`, so it seems like the service is capable of at least running the `kbdrate` command.

So finally my question is, what am I doing wrong? Is there another log file I should be looking at to find my error?

Comment: Can you `sudo su` and post the output of `kbdrate --silent --delay 250 --rate 30 && echo $?`?

Comment: `old delay 250, period 1000`
`0`, those are two seperate output lines, I cannot put the linebreak in the comment. The large period was set by me while testing.

Comment: The question mark within the code block is required, $? is the return code of the last command. Basically just want to make sure it's returning 0 and not something else

Comment: My bad, it is `0`. I edited the comment to show this.

Comment: Ah, okay. That's really strange. Systemd should see the '0' exit code and consider the process to be completed. Especially with one-shot. Can you post some of the journalctl output?

Comment: Ah apologies, I just typed your command into the console. I will try it in the service and post the results soon.

Comment: I meant in the console, you shouldn't have to change anything within the service.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119650/discussion-between-layne-bernardo-and-fergus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a discussion on the Arch BBS [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240629) where this issue is resolved.

The relevant post:

> The script is supposed to be just enabled so it can be run before logging into the terminal. If you read systemd.service(5) and systemd.exec(5) you will find that the combination of the lines
>
> StandardInput=tty
> Type=oneshot
> is at fault here. Since the tty is already in use by your user session the systemd service is waiting until your tty is free (which will never happen) before doing ExecStart. For a unit of type oneshot to be considered started whatever was started by ExecStart has to exit first.
>
> This means: systemd can never acquire the tty -> ExecStart is never called -> the service is never considered started -> systemctl waits until the service is started -> systemctl never returns.
>
> This is not a problem when booting/opening a new tty since the service will be started before your session runs on the tty, You should not really worry about that, just enable the service and go on with your life wink

Basically, you won't be able to run this command while you're logged in. You'll need to enable it and then restart before it can take effect, as it needs to run before you login to the console.